# Нет перевода для описания очереди "Запоздалые проверки"

Tags: дефект, локализация, очередь-проверок

Обнаружил отсутствие перевода на описании для очереди:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Добавил перевод:
**Edit** the answer if you think you can improve it. - [**Отредактируйте** ответ, если считаете, что можете улучшить его.](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16753)

Comment: Лучше "Исправьте" для "Edit", чтобы согласовывалось с имеющимся, например, [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers). Исправил и утвердил.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, спасибо :D